# Brand new MacBook Pro says "Service Battery"

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, power-management

Unpacked a new MacBook Pro 13" yesterday. I've been using it for a couple of hours before plugging it in for the very first time as it told me that it still had plenty of battery power left. I was surprised that it seemingly did not deplete, until the device shut off suddenly due to a completely emptied battery.

When plugging it in and restarting it, the battery icon in the menu bar said "Service Battery". Upon googling the problem I found out that [resetting the SMC](http://osxdaily.com/2019/01/14/how-reset-smc-macbook-air-pro-2018-later/) is a popular first trouble shooting step. However, a reset did not change anything, the warning remains.

Do you have any additional suggestions for me? I'd hate to take it back.

Update: After charging it to 100% I took it off the charger and the warning eventually disappeared. It's still on 100% though after having worked on it for about 3 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this happens with a new MacBook Pro, you will want to call the seller and arrange for a repair or a device replacement. It is not supposed to happen until you have used the device for years.

Comment: Actually better to return to the place you boght it from (for UK law at least)

Comment: @Mark I eventually returned it to the same Apple Store I purchased it from. They immediately exchanged the device without hesitation.